# Magento 2 - Multiple collection on same block

Tags: magento2, category, blocks, collection, product-collection

I have a block where I want 3 different collections with different category filters. I have created collection object in constructor like this:

```
protected $collection;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection,
    ...
)
{
    $this->collection = $collection;
    ...
}
```

This is my function where I am getting collection

```
public function getMyCollection($categories)
{
    $collection = $this->collection;

    //$this->productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    //Enable filter
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter(
        'status', array('eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    );

    $collection->setVisibility($this->visibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());

    $collection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $categories));

    //Setting up pagination
    $collection->setPageSize(10)
        ->setCurPage(1);
    //echo $collection->getSelect();

    return $collection->load();
}
```

The problem that I am facing is, when I call this function for first time, it runs properly, if I call it 2nd time, then it is not refreshing previous filters and adding new filters along with previous ones.

like `categories in(23,24) AND categroies in(25,26)`

How can I get multiple collections with single object with different filters everytime?

Comment: did you try using `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` ?

Comment: is `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection` wrong?

Comment: nah, I don't think so. But maybe it is better to use a collection factory instead? maybe that could be the reason for the issue?

Comment: No @magefms actually collection initialized one time, and if you apply more and more filter to any collection that it will append in that collection not reinitialize collection everytime, so it doesn't matter if I use CollectionFactory or Collection, both will be same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use collection Factory

\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,

```
$this->collectionFactory= $collectionFactory


$this->collectionFactory->create();
```

because this will return every time new instance and no filter will apply default.